# MSword Mail Merge With a TOC

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge, table-of-contents

I'm attempting to make a MSWord mail merge template where there is a section that doesn't repeat with every mail merge record.  I'd like the document to have a title page, and a TOC, and then merge each record after that section.

I tried Page Layout > Breaks > Section Break > Next Page, but the first two pages still end up repeating with every record.

My use case is text in Excel, where each row is a different heading2 title and then a few paragraphs of content.